# Custom Workflow definition for liferay document and media portlet

Tags: workflow, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I am using liferay workflow. I want to create my own workflow definition.

Now with the default workflow "Single Approver" its just directly notifying the admin that the particular document uploaded with the document and media portlet by a user. What I want is described in this image.

[image]

[image]

Whenever users under Organization A will upload any document then it will not send notification to approve the user to main ADMIN but rather it should send to Organization A Admin to approve the user.

I hope my question is understandable...

Whenever users under Organization A will upload any document then it will not send notification to approve the user to main ADMIN but rather it should send to Organization A Admin to approve the user..

I hope i have made understand my question...

I have done like this in my workflow I have single approve definition i have given that definition to one folder in media and document portlet Now there is four role they created automatically

```
1)portal Legal Reviewer - Auto generated role from workflow definition 

2)portal Content Reviewer - Autogenerated role from workflow definition 

3)organization Legal Reviewer - Autogenerated role from workflow definition 

4)organization Content Reviewer - Autogenerated role from workflow definition
```

Now whenever i upload something to that folder the notification goes to my site owner

And in that there is two option

```
1)assign to me
2)assign to -> users (who have role from above 4 they created automatically)
```

Now suppose i assign to user which have role from above four and when i open the account that user then there is no control panel or no workflow task action i can show .so how can anyone approve the content?

and one thing more where i have to edit the role in xml that it will notify the particular role described in xml not the default way to site owner

Only if i create user who have role to Administrator with the Organization Approver Role that only can access control panel and in workflow task they can find assign to and assign me notification

My defination of workflow goes Here

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<workflow-definition
    xmlns="urn:liferay.com:liferay-workflow_6.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:liferay.com:liferay-workflow_6.1.0 http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-workflow-definition_6_1_0.xsd"
>
    <name>UPLOAD Approver</name>
    <description>A single approver can approve a workflow content.</description>
    <version>1</version>
    <state>
        <name>created</name>
        <metadata>
            <![CDATA[{"xy":[36,51]}]]>
        </metadata>
        <initial>true</initial>
        <transitions>
            <transition>
                <name>review</name>
                <target>review</target>
            </transition>
        </transitions>
    </state>
    <task>
        <name>update</name>
        <metadata>
            <![CDATA[{"transitions":{"resubmit":{"bendpoints":[[303,140]]}},"xy":[328,199]}]]>
        </metadata>
        <actions>
            <action>
                <name>reject</name>
                <script>
                    <![CDATA[
                        Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowStatusManagerUtil.updateStatus(Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowConstants.toStatus("denied"), workflowContext);
                        Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowStatusManagerUtil.updateStatus(Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowConstants.toStatus("pending"), workflowContext);
                    ]]>
                </script>
                <script-language>javascript</script-language>
                <execution-type>onAssignment</execution-type>
            </action>
            <notification>
                <name>Creator Modification Notification</name>
                <template>Your submission was rejected by a reviewer, please modify and resubmit.</template>
                <template-language>text</template-language>
                <notification-type>email</notification-type>
                <execution-type>onAssignment</execution-type>
            </notification>
        </actions>
        <assignments>
            <user />
        </assignments>
        <transitions>
            <transition>
                <name>resubmit</name>
                <target>review</target>
            </transition>
        </transitions>
    </task>
    <task>
        <name>review</name>
        <metadata>
            <![CDATA[{"xy":[168,36]}]]>
        </metadata>
        <actions>
            <notification>
                <name>Review Notification</name>
                <template>You have a new submission waiting for your review in the workflow.</template>
                <template-language>text</template-language>
                <notification-type>email</notification-type>
                <execution-type>onAssignment</execution-type>
            </notification>
            <notification>
                <name>Review Completion Notification</name>
                <template>
                    Your submission has been reviewed and the reviewer has applied the following ${taskComments}.</template>
                <template-language>freemarker</template-language>
                <notification-type>email</notification-type>
                <recipients>
                    <user />
                </recipients>
                <execution-type>onExit</execution-type>
            </notification>
        </actions>
        <assignments>
            <roles>
                <role>
                    <role-type>organization</role-type>
                    <name>Organization APPROVER</name>
                </role>
                <role>
                    <role-type>organization</role-type>
                    <name>Organization Content Reviewer</name>
                </role>
                <role>
                    <role-type>organization</role-type>
                    <name>Organization Owner</name>
                </role>

                <role>
                    <role-type>regular</role-type>
                    <name>Portal Content Reviewer</name>
                </role>
                <role>
                    <role-type>site</role-type>
                    <name>Site Administrator</name>
                </role>
                <role>
                    <role-type>site</role-type>
                    <name>Site Content Reviewer</name>
                </role>

            </roles>
        </assignments>
        <transitions>
            <transition>
                <name>approve</name>
                <target>approved</target>
            </transition>
            <transition>
                <name>reject</name>
                <target>update</target>
                <default>false</default>
            </transition>
        </transitions>
    </task>
    <state>
        <name>approved</name>
        <metadata>
            <![CDATA[
                {"xy":[380,51]}
            ]]>
        </metadata>
        <actions>
            <action>
                <name>approve</name>
                <script>
                    <![CDATA[
                        Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowStatusManagerUtil.updateStatus(Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowConstants.toStatus("approved"), workflowContext);
                    ]]>
                </script>
                <script-language>javascript</script-language>
                <execution-type>onEntry</execution-type>
            </action>
        </actions>
    </state>
</workflow-definition>
```

I have not included two roles as follows which is in single approve definition comes by default..

```
<role>
<role-type>organization</role-type>
<name>Organization Administrator</name>
</role>

<role>
<role-type>regular</role-type>
<name>Administrator</name>
</role>
```

So whats happening now that i need to give a particular user to role of administrator as well as the organizationapprover but if i give the administrator rights to that user then only he can access the control panel and can go to the workflow task option but its not real idea to give rights of admin to user whose work is just to approve the content..so i want that somehow just give the permission to organizationapprover to use control panel but only to access workflow task option.the user cant do anything rather just use the workflow task option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the default workflow definition (singleapprover.xml or similar) you'll see that it defines the responsible roles as "Organization Approver", "Site Approver", "Approver" or "Administrator" (from memory).

You can change this - if that's the only thing you'd like to change, it's even simple to do so directly in the xml file. You'll find it within the plugin or in Liferay's sourcecontrol on [github](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/master/webs/kaleo-web/docroot/WEB-INF/src/META-INF/definitions). You probably only need to remove the Administrator from the list of responsible roles, then make the people you want to be responsible member of the "Site Approver" role for their relevant sites.

Done

Edit: I don't fully understand your comment below, but the solution I gave assumes that your users are structured in either organizations or sites - in that case, you can have a user being "Site Approver" or "Organization approver" within that organization. All content that is created within the scope of the site or organization will be required to be approved by the approver within that grouping.

In case you upload all the content in the same site, but have different user's assignments, you'll most likely need to go with some scripted assignments (you can script certain parts of the workflow system) but that would go beyond anything I could explain in a few words here. I could point you to the currently [available documentation](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/creating-process-definitio-2) but I doubt this will be enough to illustrate what I'm talking about - sorry

Comment: when i add single approve definition in my portlet and then there's default role is created and when i gave any user to approve or review with assign to option the control panel not displaying so how can i go to the workflow task from that reviewer user account

Answer (score 0):

For Particular User like (A), you assigned some role like Organization APPROVER etc. , for that particular role, you can define permission like as access resource in control panel.